# How can I know the PORT of jetty when it is initializing?

Tags: jetty, port

I use "bin/jetty.sh start" to start my server, How can I know the PORT of jetty when it is initializing in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you are using jetty.sh to start jetty, it is hard coded to a particular port in the start.ini, jetty.xml, or jetty-http.xml files, or it is passed in via the -Djetty.port property.

If you are starting up jetty with a declared port of 0, a random port will be assigned and you will have to comb the output for a line akin to:

Jetty 9:

> 013-05-24 11:31:57.465:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started
>   ServerConnector@6291d9aa{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}

Jetty 7/8 it would likely be a oejs.SelectChannelConnector

Answer (score 0):

I found my jetty.port in the JETTY_HOME/start.d/http.ini which look like this:

```
#
# Initialize module http
#
--module=http
## HTTP Connector Configuration
jetty.port=8081
http.timeout=30000
```

The default jetty.port is 8080, and I change it to 8081.

If the file doesn't exist, you can found the file JETTY_HOME/start.ini and add

```
--module=http
jetty.port=8081
```

to it.

Also you can run jetty in terminal to add agruments --port 8081.